# How to port 4.0 blend files to older versions of Blender

Tags: blend-files

Due to my computer's graphics I am unable to use Blender 4.0+. Some models I am interested in are made in that version. Is there a way to port these models to an older blender version?

Comment: Try to append from the 4.0 files (but that may fail).

Comment: *"E.g. Blender 3.6 LTS is able to open the new Mesh data from Blender 4.0 onward, and to save it back into a format compatible with all Blender 3.x versions."* from https://developer.blender.org/docs/handbook/guidelines/compatibility_handling_for_blend_files/

Comment: @Blunder when I open 4.0 files in 3.6 it gives me a warnign that data loss could occur if I save.

Comment: yes, that's a normal warning. If you want to be on the safe side, use the menu item *File > Append ...*, as suggested by *lemon*. I've just added the link for the additional info about compatibility and to make it clear that only Blender 3.6 LTS can read both formats (3.x and 4.0). Earlier versions immediately crash when you try to open a 4.0 blend file.