Is there any data lost opening 4.0+ files in Blender 3.6?
Due to my computer's graphics card, Blender 3.6 is the latest version I can open. I am able to open 4.0+ files fine, but was wondering if there's anything to look out for.
I'm specifically asking if there are any changes in the file I should be aware of when opening a 4.0+ file in 3.6. For example, when a 3.4+ file is opened in 3.3, any mix color node becomes undefined because of the node update that happened in 3.4. Does anything like that occur when a 4.0+ file is opened in 3.6?

Of course. You can generally expect better results for adjacent minor versions like 4.0 and 4.1, but some data loss is inevitable, because features change between versions. Between major versions like 3.x and 4.x in some cases you may expect complete incompatibility. See more here

I don't see how you can get a meaningful answer to what you are specifically asking. Have you had any problems with the files you have opened? In your other question related to this subject: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/310887/how-to-port-4-0-blend-files-to-older-versions-of-blender the comment from Blunder on Feb 1 is IMHO about as good as it gets. Here are a couple more compatibility links, but you have probably already seen something similar. https://developer.blender.org/docs/release_notes/compatibility/ https://developer.blender.org/docs/release_notes/4.0/#compatibility

You might try asking on https://blenderartists.org/ to see if anyone there can add any information for you.
